# Migrate when changing the connection from a standalone DB to a Read/Write configuration DB in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

As for what we want to achieve, we have data in the existing DB and we want to synchronize that data to the DB for READ.

```
docker-compose.yml

version: "3"
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: "${WWWGROUP}"
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
        ports:
            - "${APP_PORT:-80}:80"
            - "${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}"
        environment:
            WWWUSER: "${WWWUSER}"
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: "${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}"
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: "${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}"
        volumes:
            - ".:/var/www/html"
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - mysql_read

    mysql:
        image: "mysql/mysql-server:8.0"
        ports:
            - "${FORWARD_WRITE_DB_PORT:-3307}:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${WRITE_DB_PASSWORD}"
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "${WRITE_DB_DATABASE}"
            MYSQL_USER: "${WRITE_DB_USERNAME}"
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${WRITE_DB_PASSWORD}"
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - "sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
            - "./vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh"
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - "-p${WRITE_DB_PASSWORD}"
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s

    mysql_read:
        image: "mysql/mysql-server:8.0"
        ports:
            - "${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${READ_DB_PASSWORD}"
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "${READ_DB_DATABASE}"
            MYSQL_USER: "${READ_DB_USERNAME}"
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${READ_DB_PASSWORD}"
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - "mysql-read:/var/lib/mysql"
            - "./vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh"
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - "-p${READ_DB_PASSWORD}"
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    mysql-read:
        driver: local
```

We created two DBs with Docker and changed the Connection information as follows.

```
database.php
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url'    => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host'           => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port'           => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database'       => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'       => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'       => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'unix_socket'    => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset'        => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation'      => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'         => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict'         => true,
            'engine'         => null,
            'options'        => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

```
database.php

'mysql' => [
            'url'    => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'read' => [
                'host' => env('READ_DB_HOST'),
                'port' => env('READ_DB_PORT', '3306'),

            ],
            'write' => [
                'host' => env('WRITE_DB_HOST'),
                'port' => env('WRITE_DB_PORT', '3306'),

            ],
            'database'       => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'       => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'       => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'sticky' => true,
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'unix_socket'    => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset'        => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation'      => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'         => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict'         => true,
            'engine'         => null,
            'options'        => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

The following error occurs when executing migrate.

```
➤ php artisan migrate --database=read

   InvalidArgumentException 

  Database connection [read] not configured.

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php:173
    169▕         // If the configuration doesn't exist, we'll throw an exception and bail.
    170▕         $connections = $this->app['config']['database.connections'];
    171▕ 
    172▕         if (is_null($config = Arr::get($connections, $name))) {
  ➜ 173▕             throw new InvalidArgumentException("Database connection [{$name}] not configured.");
    174▕         }
    175▕ 
    176▕         return (new ConfigurationUrlParser)
    177▕                     ->parseConfiguration($config);

      +25 vendor frames 

  26  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I am still getting this error when I run `php artisan config:clear` .

If I delete the data from the existing DB and do php artisan migrate again, will it migrate to the DB for read?

I have looked on various sites and none of them have addressed this issue.
Maybe this is not the way to do it in the first place, but if there is a solution, please let me know.

Comment: The database connection is still `mysql`, It should automatically do the rest

Comment: The migration always changes the write. The replica(read) sync should not be done in laravel.

Comment: If I don't migrate the DB for Read, I get errors in listing, etc. Is there a certain timing when the synchronization starts?

Comment: Read about aws rds replicas or whatever hosting provider are you using. Your approach is not ok.